# What are the good practises for CONTENT i18n in grails

Tags: grails, internationalization

I'm trying to implement i18n features in my grails app, but not only for messages (menus, labels, etc...). I'm trying to do it for the actual text fields of my domain classes.

So far, my solution consists of creating a domain class like this :

```
class LocalizedText {
    String text
    Locale locale
    static hasMany=[translations : LocalizedText]

    String getTranslation(String locale) {
        def translation = this.translations.find(locale:locale)
        if (translation != null) { 
            return translation 
        } else { 
            return this
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for example I would have this domain class with a single translatable field :

```
class News {
    LocalizedText contents
    // [...]
}
```

Then, on my controller, I check the lang parameter and pick up a translation if it exists, or the default language if no translation is available for the given locale.
e.g. :

```
class NewsController {
    def list = {
         def newsContents = []
         News.list().each {
             newsContents << [contents : it.contents.getTranslation(params.lang)]
         }
         [news : newsContents]
    }
}
```

Sorry if there are errors but this is me coding ideas out of my head in a web form :-)

I believe there are much cleaner solutions out there, so I just wanted you to get me started on this complex topic.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the "i18n Fields" plugin.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that, this was 2011 and probably in Grails 1.x.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and ended up with the basically the same implementation:

```
class Translatable {

    Map<String, String> values = [:]

    static mapping = {
        columns {
            values column: 'val'
        }
        values type: 'text', lazy: false
    }

    def putAt(key, value) {
        values[key.toString()] = value.toString()
        return value
    }

    def getAt(key) {
        return values[key.toString()]
    }
}
```

The putAt and getAt methods allows you to treat the object as a map:

```
Translatable translatable = new Translatable()
translatable[Locale.ENGLISH] = "TexT"
prinlnt translatable[Locale.ENGLISH]
```

Comment: Thanks Marijn. I'll leave the question unanswered for now just in case someone has other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I used

```
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder

/**
 * ML = Multi Language
 * */
class MLString {

    String english
    String spanish

    boolean hasLanguage(String language){
        switch (language){
            case 'en':
                return english?.trim()
            case 'es':
                return spanish?.trim()
            default:
                return false
        }
    }

    String getLanguage(String language){
        switch (language){
            case 'en':
                return english
            case 'es':
                return spanish
            default:
                return ''
        }
    }

    String toString() {
        String language = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage()
        if (hasLanguage(language)){
            return getLanguage(language)
        } else {
            return getLanguage('en')
        }
    }

    static constraints = {
        english nullable: true
        spanish nullable: true
    }

}
```